# Let $p$ be a prime and let $F$ be a field with $p^k$ elements and $K$ a subfield. Show that $Gal(F : K)$ is a cyclic group of order $[F : K]$.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, cyclic-groups

My attempt:

Consider the map $σ : F→ F$ such that $∀a ∈ F, σ(a) = a^p$. Then $σ$ is a field automorphism of $F$.

$ker(σ) = 0$ and since $F$ is a finite field, $σ ∈ Gal(F : K)$, the galois group of order $k$.
Since the order of the galois group is $k$ it is generated by $σ$ so we can deduce that $Gal(F : K)$ is a cyclic group $Z_n$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, 
$|G| = |Gal(F : K)| = [F : K]$, for the field extension 
$F : K$ of finite degree.

$Gal(F : K)$ is a cyclic group of order $[F : K]$.

Comment: But you haven't proved that $\sigma$ has order $k$. You haven't excluded the possibility that $\sigma$ generates a proper subgroup of the Galois group.

Answer (score 0):

consider $\sigma$ from F to F such that $\sigma$(a)=$a^p$ then you can easily show that this an element of Galois group of order k And order of Galois group is k so it generated by $\sigma$.Therefore Galois group is cyclic.

Comment: That's only if $K$ is $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, I think. You probably need to use $|K|$ in the general case instead of $p$. That being said, $\operatorname{Gal}(F:K)$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(F:\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$